# Does C++ compiler treat all postfix operator overloading as same (postfix version of - and --)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unary-operator, postfix-operator

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Int32 {
    int num;
public:
    Int32(int num = 0) : num(num) {}
    ~Int32() {}
    int value() { return num; }
    Int32 & operator - (int x) { cout << "Postfix of -" << endl; return *this; }
    Int32 & operator -- (int x) { cout << "Postfix of --" << endl; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    Int32 x(100);
    x--;
    x-;  // [Error] expected primary-expression before ';' token
    x.operator-(0);
    return 0;
}
```

From the above code I overloaded **postfix increment** and **postfix unary minus**. I know **postfix unary minus** doesn't make sense, but I wonder why I have compilation error for **x-** and don't have any issue with **x--** and **x.operator-(0)** operations.

I compiled this code in DevC++ and I got following error.

```
[Error] expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

What is wrong with **x-** ?

Comment: x- doesn't exist. where you use this operator? there will be only unary minus.

Comment: @Sanjeev: His point is that the compiler lets him declare a function that is a postfix unary minus operator, and he can even call it, but he can't use the operator syntax.

Comment: Parsing is done independently of overload resolution. `x-;` fails because the language grammar doesn't allow it.

Comment: You can define the function because you can call it using the `x.operator-()` syntax.

Comment: That's not a "unary postfix `-` operator", it's a "binary infix `-` operator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with `x-` ?

Nothing wrong with it; This by language design. You will see the same error with

```
1 - ;
```

meaning, the `operator -` expect an argument to work with like you did it in the next line

```
x.operator-(0);
```

Comment: `x--;` also expecting one argument and implicitly ZERO has passed. I am expecting same for `x-;`.

As @Barmer said, parsing is done independently of overload resolution.
Does not mean it I can use any operator syntax to call `Int32 & operator - (int x)`?

Comment: @vinothkumar That is for `x - 0` (or any `Int32{} - int{}`)